# Relation between Rand index and accuracy

Tags: clustering, error, model-evaluation, accuracy

I am solving a problem on  binary classification. The Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rand_index) of the Rand index states that for binary classification the Rand index is equivalent to the accuracy:

$$
R I=\frac{T P+T N}{T P+F P+F N+T N}
$$

Is this statement right?. I am solving a binary classification problem. I have computed the accuracy and the rand index using `sklearn.metrics.rand_score`. Nevertheless they lead to a different result. I have found a similar question in [https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/344281/difference-between-accuracy-and-rand-index-r#:~:text=Rand%20index%20is%20accuracy%20computed,is%20invariant%20to%20renaming%20clusters](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/344281/difference-between-accuracy-and-rand-index-r#:%7E:text=Rand%20index%20is%20accuracy%20computed,is%20invariant%20to%20renaming%20clusters) but it is not the same case since I have checked that the accuracy doesn't correspond to the Rand neither for the clustering nor for the permutation of the clustering.

Comment: I believe this **is** the same question. It’s not about permuting the clustering. It’s about considering pairs of items to be clustered: were they grouped together or not? The Rand index is the accuracy over these pairs. That’s the gist of the answer to the other question, as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [difference between accuracy and Rand index (R)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/344281/difference-between-accuracy-and-rand-index-r)